# How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have a large data set of time periods, defined by a 'start' and and an 'end' column. Some of the periods overlap.

I would like to combine (flatten / merge / collapse) all overlapping time periods to have one 'start' value and one 'end' value.

Some example data:

```
  ID      start        end
1  A 2013-01-01 2013-01-05
2  A 2013-01-01 2013-01-05
3  A 2013-01-02 2013-01-03
4  A 2013-01-04 2013-01-06
5  A 2013-01-07 2013-01-09
6  A 2013-01-08 2013-01-11
7  A 2013-01-12 2013-01-15
```

Desired result:

```
  ID      start        end
1  A 2013-01-01 2013-01-06
2  A 2013-01-07 2013-01-11
3  A 2013-01-12 2013-01-15
```

What I have tried:

```
  require(dplyr)
  data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "A"), 
    start = structure(c(1356998400, 1356998400, 1357084800, 1357257600, 
    1357516800, 1357603200, 1357948800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), end = structure(c(1357344000, 1357344000, 1357171200, 
    1357430400, 1357689600, 1357862400, 1358208000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("ID", "start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")

remove.overlaps <- function(data){
data2 <- data
for ( i in 1:length(unique(data$start))) {
x3 <- filter(data2, start>=data$start[i] & start<=data$end[i])
x4 <- x3[1,]
x4$end <- max(x3$end)
data2 <- filter(data2, start<data$start[i] | start>data$end[i])
data2 <- rbind(data2,x4)  
}
data2 <- na.omit(data2)}

data <- remove.overlaps(data)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. The basic idea here is to compare lagged `start` date with the maximum end date "until now" using the `cummax` function and create an index that will separate the data into groups

```
data %>%
  arrange(ID, start) %>% # as suggested by @Jonno in case the data is unsorted
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(start)) >
                     cummax(as.numeric(end)))[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(ID, indx) %>%
  summarise(start = first(start), end = last(end))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: ID
# 
#   ID indx      start        end
# 1  A    0 2013-01-01 2013-01-06
# 2  A    1 2013-01-07 2013-01-11
# 3  A    2 2013-01-12 2013-01-15
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! Question though, when I used the function on the real data set the dates ended up kept in second format I had to wrap the summarise variables in as.POSIXct() to convert them back any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... When I save the result in some variable , both `start` and `end` are of class `POSIXct`...

Comment: Btw if you use multiple ID's you have to arrange by arrange(data, ID, start) as lag is not affected by grouping and so may take the dates from outside the ID group messing up the final structure. This wasn't part of the question but I found out the hard way afterwords.

Comment: What does the `[-n()]` do? I was able to adapt this to my own needs (similar situation but with an allowance of 90 days between dates still counting as "overlapping") but I had to copy the `[-n()]` verbatim without really understanding what it does.

Comment: Aha! I figured it out. (it's removing the last item in the `cumsum` to accommodate the added `0` at the beginning of the vector.)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think your solution makes the assumption that the data is ordered by the start date. If you change the order of the rows, the result might also changes. I'll therefore suggest adding arrange(ID,start) after the grouping is done.

Comment: @peer, yes, this was already mentioed in the comments above and the other answers.

Comment: Following up on @Dannid 's comment, how can one adapt this code to allow touching or very close intervals to be merged, i.e. let's say <5-day gap?

Comment: @Dannid Can you explain a bit more? I know n() as a row count and [] for indexing, but the cumsum is an integer. So if we're grouping by ID and there are 7 rows, what does it mean to get the -7th index of an integer within a vector? How does c(0, 2[-7]) return 1?

Comment: @NicholasHassan The cumsum output is a vector of cumulative sums for each entry. In this case, we're getting the cumulative sum of the following: is the lead(start) later than the max end for this group? Since this is grouped by ID, the sum - that is the number of times the lead(start) for the group exceeds the max(end) will be some integer. I'm not sure if it's guaranteed that the output is a vector of ever-increasing values, but that happened in the example (the data is first sorted by start). To create a 0-based index, we'll need to prepend "0" and then remove the last element (-n()).

Comment: Replacing first and last by min and max works as stated in the next post. This code gives an error in some cases (explained in the next post also).

Answer (score 18):

@David Arenburg's answer is great - but I ran into an issue where an earlier interval ended after a later interval - but using `last` in the `summarise` call resulted in the wrong end date. I'd suggest changing `first(start)` and `last(end)` to `min(start)` and `max(end)`

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(start)) >
                     cummax(as.numeric(end)))[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(ID, indx) %>%
  summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end))
```

Also, as @Jonno Bourne mentioned, sorting by `start` and any grouping variables is important before applying the method.

Comment: Can you explain what [-n()] means. I know n() as a row count and [] for indexing, but the cumsum is an integer. So if we're grouping by ID and there are 7 rows, what does it mean to get the -7th index of an integer within a vector? How does c(0, 2[-7]) return 1?

Comment: using `?`[`:

"For [-indexing only: i, j, ... can be logical vectors, indicating elements/slices to select. Such vectors are recycled if necessary to match the corresponding extent. i, j, ... can also be negative integers, indicating elements/slices to leave out of the selection."

thus `[-n()]` leaves out the last element of the group

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, [the `IRanges` package on Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) has some neat functions which can be used to deal with date or date time ranges. One of it is the `reduce()` function which merges overlapping or adjacent ranges.

However, there is a drawback because `IRanges` works on integer ranges (hence the name), so the convenience of using `IRanges` functions comes at the expense of converting `Date` or `POSIXct` objects to and fro.

Also, it seems that `dplyr` doesn't play well with `IRanges` (at least judged by my limited experience with `dplyr`) so I use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
library(IRanges)
library(lubridate)

setDT(data)[, {
  ir <- reduce(IRanges(as.numeric(start), as.numeric(end)))
  .(start = as_datetime(start(ir)), end = as_datetime(end(ir)))
}, by = ID]
```

> ```
>        ID      start        end
>    <fctr>     <POSc>     <POSc>
> 1:      A 2013-01-01 2013-01-06
> 2:      A 2013-01-07 2013-01-11
> 3:      A 2013-01-12 2013-01-15
> ```

A code variant is

```
setDT(data)[, as.data.table(reduce(IRanges(as.numeric(start), as.numeric(end))))[
  , lapply(.SD, as_datetime), .SDcols = -"width"], 
  by = ID]
```

In both variants the `as_datetime()` from the `lubridate` packages is used which spares to specify the origin when converting numbers to `POSIXct` objects.

Would be interesting to see a benchmark comparision of the `IRanges` approaches vs [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938694/3817004).

Comment: Other than collapsing rows that have overlapping intervals, if I would also like to take the minimum value of another column, how can we do that? e.g. `data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    start = structure(c(15706, 15706, 15707, 15709), class = "Date"), 
    end = structure(c(15710, 15710, 15708, 15711), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(3L, 7L, 8L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))` then the `value` column gives `3`.

Comment: @HNSKD, this should be posted as a separate question with its own [mcve], please. But a quick answer is: `library(data.table);
setDT(data)[order(start, end), grp := cumsum(cummax(shift(as.numeric(end), fill = 0)) < as.numeric(start))][, .(start = min(start), end = max(end), value = min(value)), by = grp]`

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can solve this problem pretty nicely with dplyr and the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package, which is designed for working with *interval vectors*, exactly like what you have here. It is inspired by IRanges, but is more suitable for use in the tidyverse and is completely generic so it can handle date intervals automatically (no need to convert to numeric and back).

The key is to combine the start/end boundaries into a single interval vector column, and then use `iv_groups()`. This merges all of the overlapping intervals in the interval vector and returns the intervals that remain after the overlaps have been merged.

It seems like you want to do this by ID, so I've also grouped by ID.

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~ID,       ~start,         ~end,
  "A", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-05",
  "A", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-05",
  "A", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03",
  "A", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-06",
  "A", "2013-01-07", "2013-01-09",
  "A", "2013-01-08", "2013-01-11",
  "A", "2013-01-12", "2013-01-15"
) %>%
  mutate(
    start = as.Date(start),
    end = as.Date(end)
  )

data
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   ID    start      end       
#>   <chr> <date>     <date>    
#> 1 A     2013-01-01 2013-01-05
#> 2 A     2013-01-01 2013-01-05
#> 3 A     2013-01-02 2013-01-03
#> 4 A     2013-01-04 2013-01-06
#> 5 A     2013-01-07 2013-01-09
#> 6 A     2013-01-08 2013-01-11
#> 7 A     2013-01-12 2013-01-15

# Combine `start` and `end` into a single interval vector column
data <- data %>%
  mutate(interval = iv(start, end), .keep = "unused")

# Note that this is a half-open interval!
data  
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   ID                    interval
#>   <chr>               <iv<date>>
#> 1 A     [2013-01-01, 2013-01-05)
#> 2 A     [2013-01-01, 2013-01-05)
#> 3 A     [2013-01-02, 2013-01-03)
#> 4 A     [2013-01-04, 2013-01-06)
#> 5 A     [2013-01-07, 2013-01-09)
#> 6 A     [2013-01-08, 2013-01-11)
#> 7 A     [2013-01-12, 2013-01-15)

# It seems like you'd want to group by ID, so lets do that.
# Then we use `iv_groups()` which merges all overlapping intervals and returns
# the intervals that remain after all the overlaps have been merged
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(interval = iv_groups(interval), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ID                    interval
#>   <chr>               <iv<date>>
#> 1 A     [2013-01-01, 2013-01-06)
#> 2 A     [2013-01-07, 2013-01-11)
#> 3 A     [2013-01-12, 2013-01-15)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert the interval back to "start" and "end" columns?

Comment: `iv_start()` and `iv_end()` extract the start/end vectors respectively

Comment: Very nice solution! I had a problem with the epi-package, since the function coarse.Lexis apparently deletes some of the intervals. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I'm a little late to the party, but I took @zach's code and re-wrote it using `data.table` below. I didn't do comprehensive testing, but this seemed to run about 20% faster than the `tidy` version. (I couldn't test the `IRange` method because the package is not yet available for  R 3.5.1)

Also, fwiw, the accepted answer doesn't capture the edge case in which one date range is totally within another (e.g., `2018-07-07` to `2017-07-14` is within `2018-05-01` to `2018-12-01`). @zach's answer does capture that edge case.

```
library(data.table)

start_col = c("2018-01-01","2018-03-01","2018-03-10","2018-03-20","2018-04-10","2018-05-01","2018-05-05","2018-05-10","2018-07-07")
end_col = c("2018-01-21","2018-03-21","2018-03-31","2018-04-09","2018-04-30","2018-05-21","2018-05-26","2018-05-30","2018-07-14")

# create fake data, double it, add ID
# change row 17, such that each ID grouping is a little different
# also adds an edge case in which one date range is totally within another
# (this is the edge case not currently captured by the accepted answer)
d <- data.table(start_col = as.Date(start_col), end_col = as.Date(end_col))
d2<- rbind(d,d)
d2[1:(.N/2), ID := 1]
d2[(.N/2 +1):.N, ID := 2]
d2[17,end_col := as.Date('2018-12-01')]

# set keys (also orders)
setkey(d2, ID, start_col, end_col)

# get rid of overlapping transactions and do the date math
squished <- d2[,.(START_DT = start_col, 
                  END_DT = end_col, 
                  indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(start_col)) > cummax(as.numeric(end_col)))[-.N])),
               keyby=ID
               ][,.(start=min(START_DT), 
                    end = max(END_DT)),
                 by=c("ID","indx")
                 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Benchmarks along with an even faster `data.table` solution

First, I echo @enmyj and @zach that the solution in the accepted answer gives erroneous results when there is one range that is completely inside another.

A faster approach that is reminiscent of the one proposed in the accepted answer:

1. Sort by `ID` and then all dates (`start` and `end` combined).
2. Subtract the cumulative sum of number of start dates by the cumulative sum of number of end dates.
3. Find the indices where this sum is `0`. The dates on these rows are the end dates of each collection of overlapping date ranges. The dates on the next row are the start dates of the next collection of overlapping date ranges. The indices can also be used to easily perform roll-up calculations of other columns.

This involves just a few vectorized calls and no grouping operations, so it is very performant.

As a function:

```
flatten <- function(dt) {
  setorder(dt[, rbindlist(.(.(ID, start, 1L), .(ID, end, -1L)))], V1, V2)[
    , .(
      ID = V1[i <- which(!cumsum(V3))],
      start = V2[c(1L, i[-length(i)] + 1L)],
      end = V2[i]
    )
  ]
}
```

### Benchmarks

The benchmarking uses a large-ish `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ivs)

data <- data.table(
  ID = sample(1e3, 1e5, 1),
  start = as.Date(sample(1e4:2e4, 1e5, 1), origin = "1970-01-01")
)[, end := start + sample(100)]

fCum <- function(dt) {
  # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47337684/9463489
  dt %>%
    arrange(ID, start) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(start)) >
                                cummax(as.numeric(end)))[-n()])) %>%
    group_by(ID, indx) %>%
    reframe(start = min(start), end = max(end)) %>%
    select(-indx)
}

fivs <- function(dt) {
  # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71754454/9463489
  dt %>%
    mutate(interval = iv(start, end), .keep = "unused") %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    reframe(interval = iv_groups(interval)) %>%
    mutate(start = iv_start(interval), end = iv_end(interval)) %>%
    select(-interval)
}

squish <- function(dt) {
  # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890653/9463489
  setkey(dt, ID, start, end)
  dt[,.(START_DT = start, 
        END_DT = end, 
        indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(start)) > cummax(as.numeric(end)))[-.N])),
     keyby=ID
  ][,.(start=min(START_DT), 
       end = max(END_DT)),
    by=c("ID","indx")
  ][, indx := NULL]
}
```

Timings:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  flatten = flatten(dt),
  fCum = setDT(fCum(dt)),
  fivs = setDT(fivs(dt)),
  squish = squish(dt),
  times = 10,
  check = "equal",
  setup = {dt <- copy(data)}
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#>  flatten   11.4732   11.8141   13.86760   12.36580   15.9228   19.1775    10
#>     fCum 1827.1197 1876.7701 1898.24285 1908.88640 1926.6548 1939.2919    10
#>     fivs  160.2568  163.9617  173.31783  173.32095  177.3789  192.7755    10
#>   squish   62.5197   64.9126   66.26047   65.08515   67.1685   70.9916    10
```

### Aggregating other columns

The approach used by `flatten` also makes it easy to aggregate other columns in the `data.table`.

```
data[, v := runif(1e5)]

setorder(data[, rbindlist(.(.(ID, start, 1L, 0), .(ID, end, -1L, v)))], V1, V2)[
  , .(
    ID = V1[i <- which(!cumsum(V3))],
    start = V2[c(1L, i[-length(i)] + 1L)],
    end = V2[i],
    v = diff(c(0, cumsum(V4)[i]))
  )
]
#>          ID      start        end          v
#>     1:    1 1997-09-25 1997-09-27 0.40898255
#>     2:    1 1997-11-09 1997-11-30 0.44067634
#>     3:    1 1998-04-27 1998-07-17 1.73142460
#>     4:    1 1999-08-05 1999-11-05 0.41103832
#>     5:    1 1999-12-09 2000-01-26 0.90639735
#>    ---                                      
#> 60286: 1000 2023-01-06 2023-03-28 0.54727106
#> 60287: 1000 2023-07-20 2023-10-16 1.74270130
#> 60288: 1000 2024-03-24 2024-06-23 0.07110824
#> 60289: 1000 2024-07-13 2024-07-31 0.63888263
#> 60290: 1000 2024-10-02 2024-10-19 0.22872167
```