# identify consecutively overlapping segments in R

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, overlap, locf

I need to aggregate overlapping segments into a single segment ranging **all connected segments**.

Note that a simple foverlaps cannot detect connections between non overlapping but connected segments, see the example for clarification. If it would rain on my segments in my plot I am looking for the stretches of dry ground.

So far I solve this problem by an iterative algorithm but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant and stright forward way for this problem. I'm sure not the first one to face it.

I was thinking about a non-equi rolling join, but faild to implement that

```
library(data.table)
(x <- data.table(start = c(41,43,43,47,47,48,51,52,54,55,57,59), 
                  end = c(42,44,45,53,48,50,52,55,57,56,58,60)))

#     start end
#  1:    41  42
#  2:    43  44
#  3:    43  45
#  4:    47  53
#  5:    47  48
#  6:    48  50
#  7:    51  52
#  8:    52  55
#  9:    54  57
# 10:    55  56
# 11:    57  58
# 12:    59  60

setorder(x, start)[, i := .I] # i is just a helper for plotting segments
plot(NA, xlim = range(x[,.(start,end)]), ylim = rev(range(x$i)))
do.call(segments, list(x$start, x$i, x$end, x$i))

x$grp <- c(1,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4) # the grouping I am looking for
do.call(segments, list(x$start, x$i, x$end, x$i, col = x$grp))
(y <- x[, .(start = min(start), end = max(end)), k=grp])

#    grp start end
# 1:   1    41  42
# 2:   2    47  58
# 3:   3    43  45
# 4:   4    59  60

do.call(segments, list(y$start, 12.2, y$end, 12.2, col = 1:4, lwd = 3))
```

**EDIT:**

That's brilliant, thanks, cummax & cumsum do the job, Uwe's Answer is slightly better than Davids comment.

- `end[.N]` can get wrong results, try example data `x` below.
  `max(end)` is correct in all cases, and faster.

  `x <- data.table(start = c(11866, 12696, 13813, 14011, 14041), 
                     end = c(13140, 14045, 14051, 14039, 14045))`
- `min(start)` and `start[1L]` give the same (as `x` is ordered by start), the latter is faster.
- grp on the fly is significantly faster, unfortunately I need grp assigned.
- `cumsum(cummax(shift(end, fill = 0)) < start)` is significantly faster than `cumsum(c(0, start[-1L] > cummax(head(end, -1L))))`.
- I did not test the package *GenomicRanges* solution.

Comment: `x[, .(start[1L], end[.N]), by = .(grp = cumsum(c(0, start[-1L] > cummax(head(end, -1L)))))]` could work. Basically a data.table version of my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938694/3001626)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP has requested *to aggregate overlapping segments into a single segment ranging all connected segments.*

Here is another solution which uses `cummax()` and `cumsum()` to identify groups of overlapping or adjacent segments:

```
x[order(start, end), grp := cumsum(cummax(shift(end, fill = 0)) < start)][
  , .(start = min(start), end = max(end)), by = grp]
```

> ```
>    grp start end
> 1:   1    41  42
> 2:   2    43  45
> 3:   3    47  58
> 4:   4    59  60
> ```

Disclaimer: I have seen that clever approach somewhere else on SO but I cannot remember exactly where.

**Edit**:

As [David Arenburg has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091907/identify-consecutively-overlapping-segments-in-r/52092801#comment91136279_52092801), it is not necessary to create the `grp` variable separately. This can be done *on-the-fly* in the `by =` parameter:

```
x[order(start, end), .(start = min(start), end = max(end)), 
  by = .(grp = cumsum(cummax(shift(end, fill = 0)) < start))]
```

#### Visualisation

OP's plot can be amended to show also the aggregated segments (quick and dirty):

```
plot(NA, xlim = range(x[,.(start,end)]), ylim = rev(range(x$i)))
do.call(segments, list(x$start, x$i, x$end, x$i))
x[order(start, end), .(start = min(start), end = max(end)), 
  by = .(grp = cumsum(cummax(shift(end, fill = 0)) < start))][
    , segments(start, grp + 0.5, end, grp + 0.5, "red", , 4)]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to create `grp`, you can pass it directly into `by`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg there is no `grp` provided, and that is the main aim of the question. Creating the group

Comment: You mean OP wants the `grp` in their original data? Perhaps you are right

Comment: @Onyambu The OP has requested *to aggregate overlapping segments into a single segment ranging all connected segments.*

Comment: I get it.. Although just saw OP wrote *the grouping I am looking for*. its still answers the solution

Answer (score 5):

You can try a `GenomicRanges` approach. In the output each row is a group.

```
library(GenomicRanges)
x_gr <- with(x, GRanges(1, IRanges(start, end)))
as.data.table(reduce(x_gr, min.gapwidth=0))[,2:3]
   start end
1:    41  42
2:    43  45
3:    47  58
4:    59  60
```

And a visual insepection can be done using `Gviz`. Here one has to know that the package has been built for biologists and genetic information. The pattern behind are DNA bases. Hence, one has to substract 1 of the segment ends to get the correct plot.

```
library(Gviz)
ga <- Gviz::GenomeAxisTrack()
xgr <- with(x, GRanges(1, IRanges(start, end = end - 1)))
xgr_red <- reduce(xgr, min.gapwidth=1)
ga <- GenomeAxisTrack()
GT <- lapply(xgr, GeneRegionTrack)
GT_red <- lapply(xgr_red, GeneRegionTrack, fill = "lightblue")
plotTracks(c(ga, GT, GT_red),from = min(x$start), to = max(x$start)+2)
```

[image]

Comment: The group is what exactly he is looking for.

Comment: in your edit you are still using `x$grp=.....` This is a manual input of the groups. It should not be the case

Comment: @Jimbou your very first statement cleary states `#add the grouping` But we do not have the grouping.. we are supposed to create/obtain the grouping. see the answer provided by Uwe

Comment: @Onyambu I deleted my first answer. Now you can only pass `start` and `end`, then you get the expected result. Happy with that?

Comment: This tackles the question. Love it

Comment: @Jimbou Great! Thank you for updating the chart. I will delete my comments as they are no longer needed.