# Collapse/Combine Date Ranges by Grouped Rows in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID    Group    Start Date    End Date
1     A        2018-08-08    2018-08-09
1     A        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
1     A        2018-08-05    2018-08-07
1     B        2018-08-08    2018-08-09
1     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
2     A        2018-08-08    2018-08-09
2     A        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
2     A        2018-08-01    2018-08-07
2     B        2018-08-08    2018-08-09
2     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
3     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
4     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
4     B        2018-08-01    2018-08-07
```

And I'd like collapse it so that if the `Start Date` variable in one row matches the `End Date` variable in the next row, the rows are combined while grouping by the `ID` and `Group` variables:

```
ID    Group    Start Date    End Date
1     A        2018-08-05    2018-08-09
1     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-09
2     A        2018-08-01    2018-08-09
2     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-09
3     B        2018-08-07    2018-08-08
4     B        2018-08-01    2018-08-08
```

In dplyr, I know it's possible to do this through something similar to the following:

```
df %>% 
group_by(ID, Group) %>%
rowwise() %>%
do(somefunction(x){})
```

But I need help in writing the function. Or if there's a for loop or other implementation that could accomplish this, it would be much appreciated.

**Edit**
I've modified the example data for more clarity.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods-in-r/28938694#28938694 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091907/identify-consecutively-overlapping-segments-in-r. I think your dataset is not minimal enough as it does not contain cases where rows are not consecutive date periods.

Comment: @chinsoon12 You're correct. And in fact, the solution here wouldn't distinguish non-consecutive date periods. Ultimately, the function in this answer worked best: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718415/10292275. It preserves non-consecutive date ranges while also letting users adjust the amount of time between ranges to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a more flexible solution using the `IRanges` package from BioConducter. This works well for cases which are not necessarily consecutive to their neighbors:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")
require(IRanges)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(df)

df[, , as.data.table(reduce(
       IRanges(as.numeric(`Start Date`),
               as.numeric(`End Date`)),
               min.gapwidth=1L))[, lapply(.SD, as_date), .SDcols = -"width"], 
                                 .(`ID`, `Group`)]
```

In the snippet above, I'm using the `reduce` function from `IRanges` on each of the date ranges, which collapses adjacent ranges within a given tolerance, `min.gapwidth`. In this case, I've specified date ranges to be combined if they're within one day of each other (`min.gapwidth=1L`). You can set this to `0L` to combine strictly consecutive dates.

`IRanges` only takes numeric values, so I convert the dates to numeric and then I apply the `as_date` function from the `lubridate` package to convert them back to dates. I've also removed the `width` column which would tell me how many days are within each range.

Comment: I like this solution! its a bit complicated for someone who doesn't have strong familiarity with data.table and bioconductor, but it works like a charm!  One thing to note:  i think you have an extra comma in the `df[, , as.data.table(`.... section.