# Splitting a data frame into rows depending on dates

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
d1 <- data.frame(id=1,a=1,start_d1=10, end_d1=19)
d2 <- data.frame(id=1,b=2, start_d2=15, end_d2=24)
```

Actually, `start` and `end` are dates and the data frames are huge, but I want to keep it simple here.
Now I want to join on `id` and then get new rows depending on where the respective start and end dates overlap. The result should be a dataframe `d`:

```
     id   | a  | b  | start | end    
    ----------------------------
        1 | 1  | NA | 10 | 14
        1 | 1  | 2  | 15 | 19  
        1 | NA | 2  | 20 | 24
```

What I am doing right now: I join `d1`and `d2` on `id` to get `d`.
Then I apply an explicit function I wrote to each row in `d` that splits the row into new ones with the new variables `start`and `end` depending on the overlap.

This is somewhat messy. Is there a simpler approach to my problem?

Comment: Hi, What is the expected output .please ```dput()``` your expected output will be good.

Comment: Something like this ```merge```?  ```d <- merge(d1,d2,by=c('id','start','end'),all=T)```

Comment: @TusharLad No, this doesn´t give us a seperate row for the overlap of start and date

Comment: Related: [identify consecutively overlapping segments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091907/identify-consecutively-overlapping-segments-in-r)

Comment: You could use `rbind` after removing all after `_` in names of your dataframes!

Comment: @Duck No, same problem as before, the overlap doesn´t get a seperate row

Comment: @MF14 I did some sketchs but not sure if it is what you want: `a1 <- d1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(1,2)) %>% 
  separate(col = name,into = c('key','date')) %>%
  mutate(val=1:n()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = key,values_from = value) %>% select(-c(date,val))` Then `a2 <- d2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(1,2)) %>%
  separate(col = name,into = c('key','date')) %>%
  mutate(val=1:n()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = key,values_from = value) %>% select(-c(date,val))` last `a1 %>% bind_rows(a2)` and loaded `tidyverse`

Answer (score 0):

I think, joining the two datasets and then applying a function row rise and then `rbind`ing them with `do.call` seems like a reasonable approach.

I tried to come up with a `dplyr` approach, but it feels more like a abomination, than anything else.

```
d1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),a=1, start_d1=c(10,20), end_d1=c(19,29))
d2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),b=2, start_d2=c(15,25), end_d2=c(24,34))

full_join(d1,d2) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(id = .$id,
                all_seq = seq(.$start_d1, .$end_d2, by = 1),
                a = c(rep(.$a, length(seq(.$start_d1, .$end_d1, by =1))),
                      rep(NA, length(seq(.$end_d1+1, .$end_d2, by = 1)))),
                b = c(rep(NA, length(seq(.$start_d1+1, .$start_d2, by =1))),
                      rep(.$b, length(seq(.$start_d2, .$end_d2, by = 1)))))) %>% 
  mutate(classifier = case_when(!is.na(a) && is.na(b) ~ 1,
                                !is.na(a) && !is.na(b) ~ 2,
                                is.na(a) && !is.na(b) ~ 3
                                )) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(id, classifier) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(all_seq),
            end = max(all_seq),
            a = unique(a),
            b = unique(b)) %>% 
  select(-classifier)

Joining, by = "id"
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
     id start   end     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    14     1    NA
2     1    15    19     1     2
3     1    20    24    NA     2
4     2    20    24     1    NA
5     2    25    29     1     2
6     2    30    34    NA     2
```

The idea in the `do`-function is to produce a sequence of the whole period per `id`, and `a` and `b` where they have to be.