# How to identify all sequential numbers not covered by 'to' and 'from' positions?

Tags: r, sequence, large-data

I have a data table that defines the start and end coordinates for a set of sequnces. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(from = c(7, 22, 35, 21, 50),
              to = c(13, 29, 43, 31, 60))
```

Given start and end coordinates (ie 1 and 100), I am trying to identify all integers not covered by the sequences, with the same output format. For example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(from = c(1, 14, 32, 44, 61),
              to = c(6, 20, 34, 49, 100))
```

Here is my current attempt, in which I vectorise the sequences in df1 and then identify all integers that do not match the sequence 1:100.

```
seq2 <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))
seq <- c(1:100)
df1_int <- unlist(seq2(from = df1$from, to = df1$to))
df1_int <- unique(df1_int)
df2_int <- seq[!seq %in% df1_int]
all(diff(df2_int) == 1)
```

However, this method is too slow for the dataset I want to apply it to (~100,000,000 integers), and I do not know how to reformat the vector df2_int into a dataframe in the format of df2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

NB: The sequences in df1 do not always start with the lowest integer (eg a sequence could run from 13 to 7, as opposed to from 7 to 13). There could also be sequences with only one integer (eg from 7 to 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need a fast solution we could attempt a base R approach using `setdiff` and `split`. The vectorization we leave to `mapply`. To find the factors where to `split` we use `findInterval`. To get the elements' start and end points of the resulting list we clear with `range`.

```
d <- setdiff(1:100, unlist(mapply(seq.default, df1[, 1], df1[, 2])))
t(sapply(split(d, findInterval(d, d[which(c(1, diff(d)) > 1)])), range))
#   [,1] [,2]
# 0    1    6
# 1   14   20
# 2   32   34
# 3   44   49
# 4   61  100
```

**Benchmark**

As we can see from the benchmark, we have achieved a pretty fast solution.

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
        purrr 1575.479 1593.2110 1634.3573 1604.9475 1634.033 2028.095   100   b
 findInterval  250.801  256.9245  276.8609  273.3815  281.673  498.285   100  a
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Should have read the question better. This is basically your current approach.

You can `pmap` over your input with the `seq` function, and `unlist` that to get a vector of all values. Then `setdiff` to get the missing values. Using `diff` and `cumsum` you can create a grouping variable for the missing values, grouping them into from-to pairs. Then split the missing value vector by the grouping var and `map` over that to create one row of output for each group.

```
library(purrr)

miss <- setdiff(1:100, unlist(pmap(df1, seq)))
i <- 
  miss %>% 
    diff %>% 
    `>`(1) %>% 
    rev %>%
    cumsum %>% 
    rev 

map_df(split(miss, c(i, 0)), ~list(from = head(.x, 1), to = tail(.x, 1))) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(from)


# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#    from    to
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1     6
# 2    14    20
# 3    32    34
# 4    44    49
# 5    61   100
```

Comment: Also, the last step in `base R`, `t(sapply(split(miss, c(i, 0)), range))[5:1, ]`

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing idea from [How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods/28938694#28938694) but in a `data.table` approach instead:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setorder(df1, from, to)

maxn <- 100L    

#see linked post
df1[, g := c(0, cumsum(shift(from, -1L) > cummax(to))[-.N])]

#get desired output
df1[, .(from=max(to)+1L, to=min(from)-1L), by=.(g)][, 
    .(from=c(1L, from), to=c(to, maxn))]
```

Hopefully, this is fast enough for your actual dataset with 100mio integers.