# Find overlap of multiple ranges in data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, overlap

I would like to find the overlapping part of multiple ranges which are given rowise in a data.table object.

An example would be:

```
t <- data.table(a = c(3,4,5), b = c(13,12,19))
```

So we have the ranges:

3 - 13, 
4 - 12, 
5 - 19

Hence the overlapping range would be:

5 - 12

In case of an additional range 19 - 22 the overlap should return NA - NA or 0 - 0 since there is no overlap.

I found solutions for similar problems like spatstat.utils:: intersect.ranges(). However this works only on two vectors and is hard to implement in a data.table

```
    DT[,.(o.l = function()[1], o.r = function()[2], by=.()]
```

manner which I would really like to do if possible,..

As output for this example I would like to have:

```
t <- data.table(a = c(3,4,5), b = c(13,12,19), o.l = c(5,5,5), o.r = c(12,12,12))
```

Comment: Check with `foverlaps`

Comment: I have used foverlaps to join two data.tables, but would not know how to apply it in this context now

Comment: `data.table(a = c(3,4,5), b = c(13,12,19))[, .(max(a), min(b))]`

Comment: thank you, that would of course work for that example. I adapted the question a bit to account for that case too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-line example:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(a = c(3,4,5), b = c(13,12,19))

dt[, c("o.l", "o.r") := as.list(range(Reduce(intersect, mapply(seq, a, b, 1))))]

dt
#    a  b o.l o.r
# 1: 3 13   5  12
# 2: 4 12   5  12
# 3: 5 19   5  12
```

Where the core of the problem is

```
dt = data.table(a = c(3,4,5), b = c(13,12,19))
dt[, Reduce(intersect, mapply(seq, a, b, 1))]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing idea from David Aurenburg answer in [How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods/28938694#28938694), here is another possible approach:

```
DT[, g := c(0L, cumsum(shift(a, -1L) >= cummax(b))[-.N])][, 
    c("ol", "or") := .(max(a), min(b)), g]
```

data:

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(3,4,5,19,20,24), b = c(13,12,19,22,23,25))
```

output:

```
    a  b g ol or
1:  3 13 0  5 12
2:  4 12 0  5 12
3:  5 19 0  5 12
4: 19 22 1 20 22
5: 20 23 1 20 22
6: 24 25 2 24 25
```