# Merge overlapping time periods with milliseconds in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct

I'm trying to find a way of merging overlapping time intervals that can deal with milliseconds.

Three potential options have been posted here:
[How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods)

However, I don't need to group by ID, and so am finding the `dplyr` and `data.table` methods confusing (I'm not sure whether they can deal with milliseconds, as I can't get them to work).

I have managed to get the `IRanges` solution working, but it converts `POSIXct` objects to `as.numeric` integers to calculate the overlaps. So, I'm assuming this is why milliseconds are absent from the output?

The lack of milliseconds doesn't seem to be a display issue, as when I subtract the resulting start and end times, I get integer results in seconds.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
start <- c("2019-07-15 21:32:43.565",
           "2019-07-15 21:32:43.634",
           "2019-07-15 21:32:54.301",
           "2019-07-15 21:34:08.506",
           "2019-07-15 21:34:09.957")

end <- c("2019-07-15 21:32:48.445",
         "2019-07-15 21:32:49.045",
         "2019-07-15 21:32:54.801",
         "2019-07-15 21:34:10.111",
         "2019-07-15 21:34:10.236")

df <- data.frame(start, end)
```

The output I get from the `IRanges` solution:

```
                start                 end
1 2019-07-15 21:32:43 2019-07-15 21:32:49
2 2019-07-15 21:32:54 2019-07-15 21:32:54
3 2019-07-15 21:34:08 2019-07-15 21:34:10
```

And the desired result:

```
                    start                     end
1 2019-07-15 21:32:43.565 2019-07-15 21:32:49.045
2 2019-07-15 21:32:54.301 2019-07-15 21:32:54.801
3 2019-07-15 21:34:08.506 2019-07-15 21:34:10.236
```

Suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your output - the last two periods in your data frame don't overlap.

Comment: Thanks Allan - apologies, I've corrected the sample so the last two periods now overlap.

Comment: Thanks Pajul - I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it is quite easy to preserve milliseconds if you use `POSIXlt` format. Although there are faster ways to calculate the overlap, it's fast enough for most purposes to just loop through the data frame.

Here's a reproducible example.

```r
start <- c("2019-07-15 21:32:43.565",
           "2019-07-15 21:32:43.634",
           "2019-07-15 21:32:54.301",
           "2019-07-15 21:34:08.506",
           "2019-07-15 21:34:09.957")

end <- c("2019-07-15 21:32:48.445",
         "2019-07-15 21:32:49.045",
         "2019-07-15 21:32:54.801",
         "2019-07-15 21:34:10.111",
         "2019-07-15 21:34:10.236")

df    <- data.frame(start = as.POSIXlt(start), end = as.POSIXlt(end))

i <- 1

df <- data.frame(start = as.POSIXlt(start), end = as.POSIXlt(end))

while(i < nrow(df))
{
  overlaps <- which(df$start < df$end[i] & df$end > df$start[i])
  if(length(overlaps) > 1)
  {
    df$end[i] <- max(df$end[overlaps])
    df <- df[-overlaps[-which(overlaps == i)], ]
    i <- i - 1
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```

So now our data frame doesn't have overlaps:

```
df
#>                 start                 end
#> 1 2019-07-15 21:32:43 2019-07-15 21:32:49
#> 3 2019-07-15 21:32:54 2019-07-15 21:32:54
#> 4 2019-07-15 21:34:08 2019-07-15 21:34:10
```

Although it appears we have lost the milliseconds, this is just a display issue, as we can show by doing this:

```
df$end - df$start
#> Time differences in secs
#> [1] 5.48 0.50 1.73

as.numeric(df$end - df$start)
#> [1] 5.48 0.50 1.73
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do here is to use the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org) package (for a true sub-second precision date-time type) along with the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package (for merging overlapping intervals).

Using POSIXct for sub-second date-times can be a bit challenging for various reasons, which I've talked about [here](https://clock.r-lib.org/articles/faq.html#where-did-my-posixct-subseconds-go).

The key here is `iv_groups()`, which merges all overlapping intervals and returns the intervals that remain after all of the overlaps have been merged. It is also backed by a C implementation that is very fast.

```r
library(clock)
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  start = c(
    "2019-07-15 21:32:43.565", "2019-07-15 21:32:43.634",
    "2019-07-15 21:32:54.301", "2019-07-15 21:34:08.506",
    "2019-07-15 21:34:09.957"
  ),
  end = c(
    "2019-07-15 21:32:48.445", "2019-07-15 21:32:49.045",
    "2019-07-15 21:32:54.801", "2019-07-15 21:34:10.111",
    "2019-07-15 21:34:10.236"
  )
)

# Parse into "naive time" (i.e. with a yet-to-be-defined time zone)
# using a millisecond precision
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    start = naive_time_parse(start, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", precision = "millisecond"),
    end = naive_time_parse(end, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", precision = "millisecond"),
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   start                   end                    
#>   <tp<naive><milli>>      <tp<naive><milli>>     
#> 1 2019-07-15T21:32:43.565 2019-07-15T21:32:48.445
#> 2 2019-07-15T21:32:43.634 2019-07-15T21:32:49.045
#> 3 2019-07-15T21:32:54.301 2019-07-15T21:32:54.801
#> 4 2019-07-15T21:34:08.506 2019-07-15T21:34:10.111
#> 5 2019-07-15T21:34:09.957 2019-07-15T21:34:10.236

# Now combine these start/end boundaries into a single interval vector
df <- df %>%
  mutate(interval = iv(start, end), .keep = "unused")

df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>                                             interval
#>                               <iv<tp<naive><milli>>>
#> 1 [2019-07-15T21:32:43.565, 2019-07-15T21:32:48.445)
#> 2 [2019-07-15T21:32:43.634, 2019-07-15T21:32:49.045)
#> 3 [2019-07-15T21:32:54.301, 2019-07-15T21:32:54.801)
#> 4 [2019-07-15T21:34:08.506, 2019-07-15T21:34:10.111)
#> 5 [2019-07-15T21:34:09.957, 2019-07-15T21:34:10.236)

# And use `iv_groups()` to merge all overlapping intervals.
# It returns the remaining intervals after all overlaps have been removed.
df %>%
  summarise(interval = iv_groups(interval))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>                                             interval
#>                               <iv<tp<naive><milli>>>
#> 1 [2019-07-15T21:32:43.565, 2019-07-15T21:32:49.045)
#> 2 [2019-07-15T21:32:54.301, 2019-07-15T21:32:54.801)
#> 3 [2019-07-15T21:34:08.506, 2019-07-15T21:34:10.236)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>